# Is there a way to getElementsbyClassName for a class within a div within a div within a class?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to highlight the text in the comment section of a website. However, the class containing the comments cannot be accessed through getElementsByClassName. My code doesn't throw any errors it just doesn't seem to find the class.

I think it might have something to do with the fact that said class is within multiple other divs and classes. Here is screenshot of the situation:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rg2Ni9tHVQCptaozb0Qw5HRRBUwOF0qN/view?usp=sharing

The comment class looks like this:

```
<div class="sc-fAJaQT dGfKUv" dir="auto">This is the comment that `I would like to highlight</div>`
```

highlighting it through my code doesn't work.
Here is my code.

```
var locator = "sc-fAJaQT dGfKUv";
if( document.readyState !== 'loading' ) {
    console.log( 'document geladen, executing' );
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName(locator);
    for (elt of paragraphs) {
    elt.style.backgroundColor = '#FF00FF';
  }
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        console.log( 'document nicht geladen, warte...' );
        var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName(locator);
        for (elt of paragraphs) {
        elt.style.backgroundColor = '#FF00FF';
      }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to get this element?

Comment: These class names look like they're being generated as random strings at runtime. Are you sure that the class you're looking for actually exists when you run this script?

Comment: can you post the link of the website?

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t post the website. The website is a management tool for social media. Every one of our posts creates a ticket. Within every ticket we can see all the comments to our post. And every comment is within that class. So, this class exists multiple times on the website. @shkaper it only appears random. Every comment is always within this class.

Comment: Your code works. At least, when I added your code to a snippet, that text was highlighted in pink.

Comment: @Andy I know. It works with most buttons on the website. But it doesn't work with anything within the actual "feed" of comments.